# Is there a shorthand if (without else) statement  in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby

I know there is a shorthand one-line if/else statement in Ruby:

```
a ? b : c
```

Is there one for just a single `if` statement? Instead of writing this:

```
if a
  # do something
end
```

Is there a shorthand version of this?

Comment: Just a small correction in your terms: the `a ? b : c` syntax is an *expression*, not a *statement* -- it evaluates to single value.

Comment: Note that `a ? b : c` is called a [ternary expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: @JasonLeBrun: just about anything in Ruby is an expression (i.e. returns a value).

Comment: Oh, OK, so I see. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Symbolhound is useful when you're trying to search for syntax.

Comment: u.nil? ? "true":"false" .You can use this way. Works like charm for me.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use post conditions (don't mind the name, it will be evaluated ***before*** the code. And `do_something` will only be executed if condition evaluates to truthy value (i.e. not `nil` or `false`)).

```
do_something if a
```

Comment: Of course, there is also the inverse condition: `do_something unless a`.

Comment: very nice to use with parentheses, e.g. `function('a', 'b', ('c' if something))` - third argument will be `c` or `nil` depending on `something`.

Comment: well, depends on how you use it. writing something like `function(('a' if something_a), ('b' if something_b), ('c' if something_c))` is of course a mess (the function definition must be a mess in this case already), but using it for example in `haml` like `%li{ class: ('open' if something) }` works very well to add a class conditionally or not.

Answer (score 7):

```
do_something if a
```

This will first evaluate the `if` condition (in this case `a`) and if it is `true` (or in the case of `a`, not `false` or `nil`) it will execute `do_something`. If it is `false` (or `nil`) it will move on to the next line of code never running `do_something`.