# How to use if (without else) statement for multiple lines of code?

Tags: ruby

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339149/is-there-a-shorthand-if-without-else-statement-in-ruby-on-rails) taught me how I can use an if statement without an else. I need the exact same thing, but for mutiple lines of code instead of one line of code.

I have tried this, but this does not seem to work:

```
def self.foo(a)
    {
    #mutiple lines of code
    }if a == true
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very basic ruby syntax. All the [ruby control structures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#Control_Structures) can be used in *inline way*, or in *multi-line/block way*, closed with **end** keyword.

```
def self.foo(a)
  if a == true
    # mutiple lines of code
  end
end
```

For more informations about syntax and ruby best practices, you can refer to : [this ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#no-then)

Comment: Your [initial example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33217738/1) was much cleaner.

Comment: You are right, I reverted my edit, and added an extra link for more syntax options/best practices informations.

Comment: BTW, *"inline/block way"* sounds contradictory, is that supposed to be *"multi-line/block way"*?

Comment: Little silly that I didn't try this. I assumed for some reason that this if statement had to be used with an else.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, use parenteses, not curly braces:

```
def self.foo(a)
  (
    puts 'a'
    puts 'b'
  ) if a == true
end
```

Although I must warn you, this style is not at all common in ruby community. Use regular `if` syntax instead.

Comment: Oh, so it is possible this way.